# Question from an "abandoned user" with an incomplete, unaccpeted answer

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I have [this exact question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54574/field-integrity-exception-must-specify-a-namefield-of-type-text-or-autonumber).

The answer provided didn't work for me, but I finally found an answer. Since it was also unaccepted, I am not sure if the only answer solved his problem.

I would like to answer the question as is, but it will probably never be accepted. Does that matter?

I am not looking for the "points", but rather a flag that helps other searchers find the actual solution.

Should I just answer the original and never have it "accepted"? Ask it again? Or some other option?

Answer (score 5):

I think you should answer the question there. Regardless of being accepted, votes by other members usually indicate what answer is considered the most correct.